# order of element of DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, elliptic-curves, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be DVR（discrete valuation ring）, M be the only maximal ideal of $R$. We can define discrete valuation on $R$, that is,
$$\text{ord}_p(f) = \sup \{ d \in \mathbb N : f \in M^{d}  \}$$

Let $t$ be a generator for $M$.
On the other hand,arbitrary element of $R$  is generated by unit, that is,
for all $ f∈R $, $f = u\cdot t^n$ for some unit $u \in M$ and some non-negative integer $n$.

> I want to prove $\text{ord}_p(f)$＝$n$.

I can check this is true when $R＝\Bbb Z$,and p-adic valuation, but cannot prove in general.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know that DVRs are exactly local PIDs of dimension 1? If this is the case, then you have that $t$ is, up to association (i.e. multiplication by a unit), the only prime element in $R$, and by unique factorization the integer $n$ in $f=u\cdot t^n$ is uniquely determined. From this, you easily get $f\in M^n\setminus M^{n+1}$, hence $\text{ord}_{p}(f)=n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! $f＝ut・t・t・・・t∈M^n$, and $f$ canot be dévider into n＋1-tuples of primes ?

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you,but,If you were to write the reason of $f$ is not belong to $M^（n＋1）$, how would you write it?

Comment: This is the same question as your previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871349/), except with 2 replaced by $n$, and the answer I gave in that previous question works just the same here. Do you know how to prove unique prime factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$? Because what you're asking here (if stripped of the abstraction) is exactly that proof, and knowledge of that proof is certainly a prerequisite for Silverman's book.